# My function is not working. I am calling a query and wanting to call the results

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php   

 function get_subject_by_id2() {
            global $connection;
            $query = "SELECT * ";
            $query .= "FROM subjects ";
            $query .= "WHERE id= 2 ";
            $query .= "LIMIT 1";
            $result_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
            confirm_query($result_set);
            // REMEMBER:
            // if no rows are returned, fetch_array will return false
            if ($subject = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set)) {
                return $subject2;
            } else {
                return NULL;
            }
        }


echo $subject2['content1'];
echo $subject2['content2'];

?>
```

I have no idea why this is not working. Please help!

I believe it is not returning NULL, and it returns $subject2. For some reason, it does not work.

Comment: TYPO: return $subject2; should be return $subject;

Comment: I  call subject2 below in the echo

Comment: please avoid using globals :/

Comment: this is what google tells me: [pastebin.com/hVqKkj5L](http://pastebin.com/hVqKkj5L) for confirm query.

Comment: function confirm_query($result_set) {
  global $connection;
  if (!$result_set) {
   die("Database query failed: " . mysqli_error($connection));
  }
 }

Comment: you must provide a complete script if you want the community to work out the problem, otherwise the reason might simply be that the program is not complete.

Comment: besides, "it does not work" does not explain the problem. Please give us the result when running the script: error message, output?

Comment: what's the `subjects` table schema like?

Comment: please update your question with answers to my questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you even calling the function? That function isnt being called and hence it cannot return anything

```
$subject2=get_subject_by_id2();   // forgot to make this call?
echo $subject2['content1'];
echo $subject2['content2'];
```

Also as suggested by **yajakass** fix the typo

Comment: Works thank you. I am an idiot. I called the function somewhere else but did not set it equal to anything.